# Every derived table must have it's own alias - *every* derived table or just within each query?

Tags: mysql

I have this query here:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT C1.ToLoc, (SELECT ME1.EquipmentNumber FROM MajorEquipment ME1 WHERE C1.ToLoc = ME1.MEId) AS EquipmentNumber FROM MajorEquipment ME1 
  INNER JOIN CableId C1 ON C.FromLoc = ME1.MEId
  WHERE C1.FromLoc = (SELECT ME1.MEId FROM MajorEquipment ME1 WHERE ME1.EquipmentNumber = 'Equipment'))
UNION
  (SELECT DISTINCT C2.FromLoc, (SELECT ME2.EquipmentNumber FROM MajorEquipment ME2 WHERE C2.FromLoc = ME2.MEId) AS EquipmentNumber FROM MajorEquipment ME2 
  INNER JOIN CableId C2 ON C.FromLoc = ME2.MEId
  WHERE C2.ToLoc = (SELECT ME2.MEId FROM MajorEquipment ME2 WHERE ME2.EquipmentNumber = 'Equipment'));
```

As you can see, I have specified the referenced tables within each query as `C1` and `C2`, and `ME1` and `ME2`, but I'm still getting the error:

> Every derived table must have it's own alias

Is it suggesting that I need a unique alias for *every* reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your query formatted so (at least) I can read it:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT C1.ToLoc,
             (SELECT ME1.EquipmentNumber FROM MajorEquipment ME1 WHERE C1.ToLoc = ME1.MEId) AS EquipmentNumber
      FROM MajorEquipment ME1 INNER JOIN
           CableId C1
           ON C.FromLoc = ME1.MEId
      WHERE C1.FromLoc = (SELECT ME1.MEId FROM MajorEquipment ME1 WHERE ME1.EquipmentNumber = '613-MCC-050')
     ) UNION
     (SELECT DISTINCT C2.FromLoc,
             (SELECT ME2.EquipmentNumber FROM MajorEquipment ME2 WHERE C2.FromLoc = ME2.MEId) AS EquipmentNumber
      FROM MajorEquipment ME2 INNER JOIN
           CableId C2
           ON C.FromLoc = ME2.MEId
      WHERE C2.ToLoc = (SELECT ME2.MEId FROM MajorEquipment ME2 WHERE ME2.EquipmentNumber = '613-MCC-050')
     );
------^
```

The arrow highlights where the alias is missing.  Next, I don't think MySQL will accept this because the `union` subquery should all be a single query in parentheses.  You might need this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ((SELECT DISTINCT C1.ToLoc,
              (SELECT ME1.EquipmentNumber FROM MajorEquipment ME1 WHERE C1.ToLoc = ME1.MEId) AS EquipmentNumber
       FROM MajorEquipment ME1 INNER JOIN
            CableId C1
            ON C.FromLoc = ME1.MEId
       WHERE C1.FromLoc = (SELECT ME1.MEId FROM MajorEquipment ME1 WHERE ME1.EquipmentNumber = '613-MCC-050')
      ) UNION
      (SELECT DISTINCT C2.FromLoc,
              (SELECT ME2.EquipmentNumber FROM MajorEquipment ME2 WHERE C2.FromLoc = ME2.MEId) AS EquipmentNumber
       FROM MajorEquipment ME2 INNER JOIN
            CableId C2
            ON C.FromLoc = ME2.MEId
       WHERE C2.ToLoc = (SELECT ME2.MEId FROM MajorEquipment ME2 WHERE ME2.EquipmentNumber = '613-MCC-050')
      )
     ) t;
```

(To be honest, I always write queries this way so I could imagine that the extra parentheses are not needed.)

Also, the `select distinct` are unnecessary.  `union` will remove the duplicates anyway.

You can also fix your original query by removing the `SELECT * FROM` at the beginning.

Comment: How would I remove the `SELECT * FROM`? if I do that, the `UNION` query crashes?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you have a query between () you need to provide an alias if you are using the results in another SELECT.

So in the WHERE c1.FromLoc= (...) you do not need an alias.

In the SELECT * FROM (...) you need an alias (so SELECT * FROM (...) some_alias )